# ng-map: how to set origin to current location for directions?

Tags: google-maps, ng-map

I'm using AngularJS and ng-map.

How can I set the directions origin to my current location?

I've tried:

```html
<directions 
    destination="..."
    origin="current-location">
</directions>
```

But this causes the map to not render anything.

Thank you for the help to set my current location as the origin.

Karl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not supported but is on the backlog.

Allen provided the following response to acquire the current location using an API call:

https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/services/navigator_geolocation.js

NavigatorGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(pos) {
   ...
});